# HttpListenerResponse adding unwanted Set-Cookie header

Tags: c#, cookies, httplistener

I'm trying to work with the `HttpListener` class with C#, and it seems like it sends an unwanted Set-Cookie header, while preventing my cookies from being sent.

Having `HttpListenerContext context`, The request is being processed in some way, then the response part seems like that:

```
    if (responseHeaders != null)
        foreach (string header in responseHeaders.Keys)
            context.Response.Headers.Add(header, responseHeaders[header]);
    for (int i = 0; i < responseCookies.Count; i++)
    {
        context.Response.Headers.Add("Set-Cookie", responseCookies[i].ToHeaderString());
    }
oWrite(response, responseEncoding);
oClose();
```

And my extension method, `ToHeaderString()`:

```
    public static string ToHeaderString(this Cookie c)
    {
        string s = c.Name + "=" + c.Value;
        if (c.Path != null && c.Path != string.Empty)
        {
            s += "; path=" + c.Path;
        }
        if (c.Domain != null && c.Domain != string.Empty)
        {
            s += "; domain=" + c.Domain;
        }
        if (c.Expires != null)
        {
            s += "; expires=" + c.Expires.ToString("ddd, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss", new CultureInfo("en-US")) + " GMT";
        }
        return s;
    }
```

`responseHeaders` is of type `Dictionary<string, string>`, and `responseCookies` is of type `CookieCollection`. They're both populated with headers and cookies to be sent to the client.

```
Cookie userCookie = new Cookie("username", _GET["__username"], "/");
userCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(10);
_CONNECTION.responseCookies.Add(userCookie);
Cookie userSession = new Cookie("session", ses, "/");
userSession.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(10);
_CONNECTION.responseCookies.Add(userCockie);
_CONNECTION.responseCookies.Add(userSession);
```

Still, the response I'm seeing is that:

```
Date:Wed, 19 Oct 2016 11:33:21 GMT
Server:Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
Set-Cookie:username=yotam180; Max-Age=863999; Path=/, session=XCDbRv0fqbUwWC9g9xXL; Max-Age=863999; Path=/
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
```

What am I doing wrong here? Am I not using the `HttpListenerResponse` headers correctly?

Thanks!

**Edit** I have also tried using context.Response.Cookies.Add(..), but also, with no success. Is that the correct way to do that? Or is there any trick that can be used here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I eventually found where I was mistaken there.

There was an assignment, before of the code I have given, that should have been an initialization. Basically, assigning `CookieCoolection A = context.Response.Cookies` instead of `CookieCollection A = new CookieCollection`, made the `context.Response.Cookies`'s cookies to be entered to the collection twice, and I guess that what's caused the problem.